# can Query this statment in MySQL? (about regular expression and sum)

Tags: mysql

My Table Sample

```
id[int] | val[varchar]
1000    | 50,50,50
1001    | 100,20,60
1002    | 190,80,20
```

i want select val from Table with sum but argument in sum is 50+100+190

> EX QUERY:
>
> > SELECT SUM(val[REG:/(.*),.*,.*/]) FROM Table
>
> RESULT:
>
> > > 240

can MySQL possible query?

Thank for all.

Comment: i not bad design because it is example. i just doubt.

Comment: Yes, it is a bad design. But I hope this bad design is only because it is an example. @zerkms: +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not quite impossible, but it's really really ugly and it works only if your val column always contains 3 values. It's something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ',', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ',', -2), ',', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ',', -1) as valSum;
```

And I really don't recommend for you to use it. I posted the query for informational purpose only.

As already mentioned, the design is really bad for practical use.

Answer (score 0):

dun have to use regexp, can use `substring_index`

```
sum( substring_index( val, ',', 1) )
```

as explained by zerkms -- **BAD DESIGN**